# Напиши функцию change_Peter_to_Vasya(x), которая в массиве строк заменяет в каждом предложении имя Петя на Вася

Tags: python

Напиши функцию change_Peter_to_Vasya(x), которая в массиве строк заменяет в каждом предложении имя Петя на Вася. Имя всегда встречается в именительном падеже и единственном числе и не является частью другого слова.

Ввод    Вывод
3
Петя — лучший ученик в школе!
Если попросить, Петя всегда поможет.
Петя — зазнайка!    Вася — лучший ученик в школе!
Если попросить, Вася всегда поможет.
Вася — зазнайка!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score -3):

лови

```
def change_Peter_to_Vasya(x):
    result = []
    for sentence in x:
        result.append(sentence.replace('Петя', 'Вася'))
    return result

sentences = [
    'Петя — лучший ученик в школе!',
    'Если попросить, Петя всегда поможет.',
    'Петя — зазнайка!'
]

new_sentences = change_Peter_to_Vasya(sentences)

for sentence in new_sentences:
    print(sentence)
```

Вывод такой

Вася — лучший ученик в школе!
Если попросить, Вася всегда поможет.
Вася — зазнайка!

И еще вариант

```
def change_Peter_to_Vasya(x):
    return [sentence.replace('Петя', 'Вася') for sentence in x]
```

Comment: не стоит отвечать на вопросы, нарушающие правила сайта.